# Pagination with Hibernate Criteria and DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I've have already implemented pagination using the following code:

```
public Paginacao<Anuncio> consultarPaginado(int pagina, Integer cidadeId) {

            Criteria criteria = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Anuncio.class);      
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ativo", true));
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("statusLiberacao", AnunciosUtil.STATUS_ANUNCIO_LIBERADO));
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("statusVendaAnuncio", AnunciosUtil.STATUS_VENDA_ANUNCIO_DISPONIVEL));

            if (cidadeId != null) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("cidade.id", cidadeId));
            }

            criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("dataPostagem"));
            criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());

            Long count = (Long) criteria.uniqueResult();

            Paginacao<Anuncio> paginacao = new Paginacao<Anuncio>();
            int qtdPaginas = (count.intValue() / 7) + 1;

            paginacao.setQtdPaginas(qtdPaginas);

            criteria.setProjection(null);// reseta a criteria sem a projeção
            criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

            if (pagina > qtdPaginas) {
                pagina = qtdPaginas;
            }
            pagina = pagina - 1;
            criteria.setFirstResult(pagina * ConstantesGenericas.MAXIMO_OBJETOS_RETORNADOS);
            criteria.setMaxResults(ConstantesGenericas.MAXIMO_OBJETOS_RETORNADOS);

            paginacao.setRegistros(criteria.list());

            return paginacao;
        }
```

When I build the SQL query manually and submit it to the database, I get 8 results. However, when I try the above code, before setting the ResultTransformer to DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY e get 8 results (without distinct) and after setting it I get 4 results. But I should get 8 results (using DISTINCT), because when I build the SQL manually without distinct I get 11 results and when I use DISTINCT I get correctly, 8 distincts results.

What's wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After a long time looking for a solution for my problem I managed to solve it. The problem that if you create a criteria or query that retrieves toMany associations using JOINS, and 
then you use setMaxResults and set the ResultTransformer to DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY the result won't be as you expected.

As JB Nizet said, suppose you have 4 A entities, each with 3 B entities, and suppose your query retrieves all the A entities with their Bs.

In that case, the SQL query will return 12 rows. If you use setMaxResults(7), it will retrieve (for example) three rows for A1 and its Bs, three rows for A2 and its Bs, and just 1 row for A3 and its first B.

And since you have used DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY, the criteria query will return only three entities: A1, A2, and A3 (which will have an incomplete set of Bs).

To solve this, you have to set the FETCH MODE for toMany (usually collections) relationships to SELECT or SUBSELECT, and you have basically 2 ways to achieve this:

The first way is to use @FetchMode(FetchMode.SUBSELECT) annotation on your attribute, and I don't like this approach because it causes every query to use SUBSELECT FETCH to retrieve the collection. But it will work.

The other way is to set fetch modes for relationships when you build your query. I prefer this way, because I can customize the query to my needs and I don't have to use SUBSELECTS to all queries. So, I've done this way:

```
public Paginacao<Anuncio> consultarPaginado(int pagina, Integer cidadeId) {

        Criteria criteria = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Anuncio.class);      
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ativo", true));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("statusLiberacao", AnunciosUtil.STATUS_ANUNCIO_LIBERADO));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("statusVendaAnuncio", AnunciosUtil.STATUS_VENDA_ANUNCIO_DISPONIVEL));
        criteria.setFetchMode("imagens", FetchMode.SELECT);
        criteria.setFetchMode("pagamentos", FetchMode.SELECT);      

        if (cidadeId != null) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("cidade.id", cidadeId));
        }

        criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("dataPostagem"));
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());

        Long count = (Long) criteria.uniqueResult();

        Paginacao<Anuncio> paginacao = new Paginacao<Anuncio>();
        int qtdPaginas = (count.intValue() / 7) + 1;

        paginacao.setQtdPaginas(qtdPaginas);

        criteria.setProjection(null);// reseta a criteria sem a projeção
        criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

        if (pagina > qtdPaginas) {
            pagina = qtdPaginas;
        }
        pagina = pagina - 1;
        criteria.setFirstResult(pagina * ConstantesGenericas.MAXIMO_OBJETOS_RETORNADOS);
        criteria.setMaxResults(ConstantesGenericas.MAXIMO_OBJETOS_RETORNADOS);

        paginacao.setRegistros(criteria.list());

        return paginacao;
    }
```

Hope that it helps anyone else. ;D

Comment: I seriously wish your variables names were NOT in Portuguese :)

Comment: Still can't make it work.. Tried to add FetchMode.SELECT to all *ToMany collections but still without result..

Comment: Thank you! it not only worked for me but i have been looking for a solution for some days now. You found the solution and the explanation! I really really liked this post!!!

Comment: I made this work in a query where only criteria on the main table are searched, the fetchMode successfully changed inner join to select. But doesn't work in a query that checks properties on associated entities - there the join seems unavoidable.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if your query retrieves entities with toMany associations join-fetched, then pagination won't work as expected.

Indeed, suppose you have 4 A entities, each with 3 B entities, and suppose your query retrieves all the A entities with their Bs.

In that case, the SQL query will return 12 rows. If you use setMaxResults(7), it will retrieve (for example) three rows for A1 and its Bs, three rows for A2 and its Bs, and just 1 row for A3 and its first B.

And since you have used DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY, the criteria query will return only three entities: A1, A2, and A3 (which will have an incomplete set of Bs).

Comment: Yeah, I got it I have already solved it. Ant it's exactly like you said. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 12):

This was an issue for me, and it took some time to come up with a solution that works for all the scenarios I have.

What you want for each pagination page is 2 things, the total count of all results and your single page of results, but to do that you need to take 3 steps. 1) get the total count, 2) get the unique ids for your page, and 3) get the full data for the ids found in step 2. And you can do all that with a single criteria object:

1) get total count, using distinct ids (uniqueField = the name of your id in the entity class)

```
  Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(YourEntity.class);
  Projection idCountProjection = Projections.countDistinct(uniqueField);
  criteria.setProjection(idCountProjection);
  //setup criteria, joins etc here
  int totalResultCount = ((Long)criteria.uniqueResult()).intValue();
```

2) reset projection and set start and length (you want the distinct ids)

```
  criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property(uniqueField)));
  criteria.setFirstResult(start); 
  criteria.setMaxResults(length);
  List uniqueSubList = criteria.list();
```

3) reset projection and get distinct results that match ids

```
  criteria.setProjection(null);
  criteria.setFirstResult(0); criteria.setMaxResults(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
  criteria.add(Restrictions.in(uniqueField, uniqueSubList));
  criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
  List searchResults = criteria.list();
  //and now, however you want to return your results
  Map<String, Object> searchResultsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  searchResultsMap.put("searchResults", searchResults);
  searchResultsMap.put("totalResultCount", totalResultCount);
```

Comment: This is great! One note though: if you use order by some databases requires the order by column to be part of the result set for the second query. See http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/constant/ErrorCode.html#c90068 for an example.

Comment: Proper pagination requires a user-meaningful sort; e.g., by name. But step 2) only has the unique field. How to write "select distinct uniqueField from (select * from my_table order by my_field)" as a Hibernate criteria? p.s. @jontejj that link is dead.

Comment: Found a second issue here: this makes the critical assumption that doing distinct/project on the unique field WILL PRESERVE ORDER.  I don't believe that's safe.