# Is there a default max to gorm list method on domain object in grails 3.2

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0

For the life of me I cannot understand why in a controller that inherits from RestfulController, that the index method only returns 4 rows.  Is this a default setting?  The same behavior happens when I override the method, like so.

```
import grails.rest.*
import grails.converters.*

class WidgitController extends RestfulController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
    WidgitController() {
        super(Widgit)
    }

    @Override
    def index() {
        def w = Widgit.findAllWhere(isEnabled: true, [max: 10]) //w: sizec4
        def w2 = listAllResources(params) //w2: size 4
        respond w
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem comes under better focus when you look up paging.

depending on how your domain objects are spec'd out gorm will us a different resultTransformer.  In my case I had a one to many relationship that was spec'd as

```
orders(lazy:false, fetch:"join")
```

the fetch as join told gorm to do a large query and then reduce the set of data after the max offset was applied.

for more reading look into the following:

[agination-with-hibernate-criteria-and-distinct-root-entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038234/pagination-with-hibernate-criteria-and-distinct-root-entity)

[sorting-and-pagination-with-hibernate-criteria-how-it-can-go-wrong-with-joins](http://blog.xebia.com/sorting-and-pagination-with-hibernate-criteria-how-it-can-go-wrong-with-joins/)