# Hibernate Criteria : distinct entities, Fetch join and MaxResults

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

When I have a Criteria request from a root element (Company for example) with a fetchMode JOIN and an Alias LEFT_OUTER_JOIN to a collection (Employees for example), I don't manage to get distinct Companies paginated (with MaxResults and firstElement).

```
criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Company.class);

criteria.createAlias("employees", "employees", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
criteria.setFetchMode("employees", FetchMode.JOIN);

criteria.setFirstResult((pageNb - 1) * nbPerPage);
criteria.setMaxResults(nbPerPage);
```

If I ask for the firsts 20 companies, I only have 3 because the first of the results has 18 employees.

I would like to have the firsts 20 as asked but with the employees loaded to optimised the lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038234/pagination-with-hibernate-criteria-and-distinct-root-entity) that has a similar situation. When you limit your results in a criteria, hibernate will apply the limit in the SQL query, and when you work with joins/distinct root entity, in many cases, it will result in a smaller result list. The results you reported confirms this.
The workaround suggested is to change the fetch mode for your alias to `SELECT`. The result is that more than one query will be called, but surely will be less costly than lazy loading for each element.

Comment: It doesn't change anything. 
The results are the same even with the SELECT.

The fact is that I don't use the _limit_ method but the _setMaxResults_ and the _setFirstResult_.