# Get distinct values via hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm

I want to get distinct values by a parameter:

```
@Transactional
public List<data> getAllFromColumn(String identifier) {

    List<data> resultList = em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT p.market FROM data p", Data.class).getResultList();

    return resultList;
}
```

My problem is that this only returns me a `NullPointerException`. Any recommendations what is wrong, or what I can do differently?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: Your `em` is set? Are you sure the query is the problem?

Comment: @Jens EntityManager works fine. Have proved that by doing other easier queries.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300491/how-to-get-distinct-results-in-hibernate-with-joins-and-row-based-limiting-pagi] this may help you

Comment: your code mixes `data` and `Data`. Maybe just a tipo, but I think it is worth fixing it.

Comment: Also, JPQL does support 'DISTINCT'

Comment: Is this the entire code snippet? From the snippet, only em being null can result into NPE, getResultList is guaranteed to never be null. Stacktrace would help here?

Comment: @maress Just checked it again! Yep thats the codesnipped. The thing is when loading hibernate with spring I get the NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If HQL doesn't support `select distinct` (which it doesn't seem to according to the syntax), you can do this using `group by`:

```
SELECT p.market
FROM data p
GROUP BY p.market;
```

Comment: Just read sth about a criteria builder. Any recommendations for putting that into the criteria builder? What is the syntax? I appreciate your reply!

Comment: @Vivien . . . My expertise is in SQL, not Hibernate.  In this case, the query can be turned into an equivalent valid query using `group by`.