# get less result than maxResults with DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, distinct

thank a lot for view my question.

I have a 2 Entities with relationship: one-to-many. They are "staff" and "role".(One Staff has many Role)

This is "Role" in Staff :

`@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "staffId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Role> roleCollection;`

And I tried to select a specify numbers of Staff with codes:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Staff.class);
crit.setFirstResult(0);
crit.setMaxResults(20);
crit.setFetchMode("id", FetchMode.SELECT); // This solution in SOF but it not work
crit.addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
crit.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
result = crit.list();
```

I known my problem. 
 - `Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY` remove duplicate entity after getting data from Database
 - But `setMaxResults(20);` calculate  number  of results include duplicate result.

So, my List of result less than my `maxResult()`

I tried some solutions was solved on SOF, but all of them failed. I think because my config in entity class: `FetchType.EAGER` but i dont want to change it to `LAZY`

can you help me to solve it?

Comment: Use Projections.distinct. Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536868/criteria-distinct-root-entity-vs-projections-distinct

Comment: Thank @Sampisa for your support.  I'm a newbie in Hibernate. I tried with your solution. But if i use `Projections.distinct(Projections.property("id"));` It change my result collection to a Collection of Integer. I cant find any good way to transfer it back to entity.

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300491/how-to-get-distinct-results-in-hibernate-with-joins-and-row-based-limiting-pagi

Comment: Yes, It exactly i tried. And it convert Result in `criteria.list` to a list of Integer. :'( Something wrong here

Comment: Here's my error code: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to model.entity.Staff`

Comment: Sorry for not reading carefully your question. There is nothing you should do: entities that you get Staff are *obviously* distinct: you can use "distinct" only if you have - clearly - equal "values" to aggregate.

Comment: [continues] With your Criteria crit you ask to search items ordered by "id" from class Staff; primary keys are different, so entities are different.
If you instead want to get just few attributes, you must use Projections.distinct, so that results where selected properties are equals are collapsed in just one entity. If I've not understood your point, please clarify posting entities and example of data, and what you expect as result from your query. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much Sampina. My mistake was on             `crit.setFetchMode("id", FetchMode.SELECT); `

- i fixed my issue by change property "id" to "roleCollection"  which column be joined  . Before time, i didn't understand exactly about Fetch and Fetch mode.

Thank you so much again Sampina.

Answer (score 0):

When I changed to *fetch=FetchType.LAZY* in my *OneToMany* mapping, its work fine without *.setFetchMode* on criteria. Example:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "staffId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<Role> roleCollection;
```

Criteria:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Staff.class);
crit.setFirstResult(0);
crit.setMaxResults(20);
crit.addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
crit.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
result = crit.list();
```